# I need to change the name of a TextBox, not the text in the textbox. Then use that name to name a seperate textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have six textboxes.

```
|TB1|   |TB102|    |TB103|
|TB2|   |TB202|    |TB203|
```

- I need to use TB1 as a full integer, say 100.
- TB102 needs to divide TB1 in half.
- TB103 needs to divide in quarter.

Here's my code:

```
private void TB_Half_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tbFull = (TextBox)sender;   //determine which textbox is changed
    TextBox tbHalf = (TextBox)sender;   //save the name to add 02 to it later
                                        // tbHalf == tbFull + "02";?

    int ATTFull = Convert.ToInt32(tbFull.Text); //convert textbox to integer
    int ATTHalf = ATTFull / 2;               //divide by 2
    string STRback = Convert.ToString(ATTHalf); //convert integer to textbox
    //tb.Name = TBHalf + "02";                         //add 02 to tb name

    TB102.Text = STRback;   //result in TB box 02
    //how do I use TbHalf instead?
    //I need to take tbHalf and add 02 to it so I can use this code on any TextBox.
}
```

I've been trying to figure this out but once I get into [get][set] and more elaborate code I lose it. I'm a graphic designer, not really a programmer, but I'm trying to learn.

Comment: Read the question a few times, but did not understand, In your code tbfull and tbHalf point to the same control. If all you want to do is to address or access corresponding text boxes, you could use forms.controls which gives you all teh controls. Then what you could do is to use the textbox name and then search for a control with a 02 suffix added.

Comment: As an aspiring programmer who wants to use Stack Overflow as a resource for help, it behooves you to carefully read help topics on the site, such as [ask] and [mcve], as well as pages referenced at the bottom of each of those articles. Those will give you excellent advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: Everything works perfectly until I get to the bottom of the code where TB102 is.  It always writes the result to TextBox TB102.
This 'function' is activated by making a change in TB1 or TB2, but both will write to TB102.  I want a change in TB1 to write the result to TB102, and a change to TB2 to show a result in TB202. I will be adding 20 more of these sets of boxes.
@dgorti - I think you are correct that I want to use the TextBox name from the (TextBox)sender and add the 02 suffix to it.  I'm thinking it needs to be changed to a string, then back to a control? Is it simpler than that?

Comment: This feels like a [gigantic XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  You seem to be trying to use the name of controls in program logic, which would only make sense in some *very specific circumstances*, and in any other situation, you are doing something that is not only unnecessary, but extremely error prone.  In the specific circumstances that this would make sense, you would already have more knowledge of the framework to just identify that this was something necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is "change" the names of declared variables, which doesn't make any sense. The name of a variable is immutable - once you set the name, you can't change it. That's because the name of a variable isn't a value itself, but rather an arbitrary identifier of what variable you are working with.

From what I understand, you are trying to determine whether which of two text boxes triggered an event. However, using:

```
TextBox tbFull = (TextBox)sender;
TextBox tbHalf = (TextBox)sender;
```

isn't going to help you determine which text box triggered the event. All it does is give you two variables that point to the exact same value in memory, which is redundant.

To do this, you need to give your text boxes distinct names in the designer view (under "Name" in the Properties box), then use those names against sender to determine which text box triggered the event.

```
private void TB_Half_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Determine the source and target boxes
    TextBox source = (TextBox)source;
    TextBox target;

    if (sender == TB1)
        target = TB102;        // TB1triggered the event, so update TB102
    else if (sender == TB102)
        target = TB103;        // TB102 triggered the event, so update TB103
    else
        return;                // Somehow something else triggered the event, 
                               // and we don't know what to do when that happens

    // Whichever text box triggered the event, the math is the same
    target.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(source.Text) / 2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Abion47.  As @dgorti mentioned above I think I need to use the name from (TextBox)sender and find the next textbox with the suffix 02 or 03.  How can I find a control this way?

Comment: You can use `this.Controls` to get a list of all the controls connected to a Form window (where "this" is the name of the window), but that list isn't ordered in any particular way. There is no guarantee, for example, that if `TB1` is the child at index 4 then index 5 and 6 would be `TB102` and `TB103` respectively. That is why it would be easier to refer to the controls directly by name, like you are doing when you assign to `TB102.Text` in your code, rather than trying to find them manually in the complete list of controls.